# Python naming conventions guide

Tags: python, window

I would like to learn aout the naming convetions in this language, this is explained in the official documentation?, if not how I could introduce to good Python practices?

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the official python style guide. In particular, it lists some [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: thankyou for your fast and good reply

Comment: To check your code against most (not all) of PEP8's guidelines, you can install the official [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) Python package after which a simple `$ pep8 mycode.py` lints your code and provides you with a small status report of possible 'violations'.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you can reference the official Python style guide [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The naming conventions are [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

You can also check out Google's Python style guide [here](https://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide), with naming conventions addressed [here](https://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide#Naming).

*Here are some highlights from Google:*

**Names to avoid**

- single character names, except for counters or iterators
- dashes (-) in any package/module name
- __double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__ names (reserved by Python)

**Naming convention**

Note that some naming conventions differ from PEP8 and instead follow the original Google Python Style guide from which this style guide originated.

- "Internal" means internal to a module or protected or private within
  a class.
- Prepending a single underscore (_) has some support for protecting
  module variables and functions (not included with import * from).
- Prepending a double underscore (__) to an instance variable or method
  effectively serves to make the variable or method private to its
  class (using name mangling).
- Place related classes and top-level functions together in a module.
  Unlike Java, there is no need to limit yourself to one class per
  module. However, make sure the classes and top-level functions in the
  same module have high cohesion.
- Use CapWords for class names, but lower_with_under.py for module
  names. Naming examples